# How typescript checks the specific type of a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
type ValueType = string | number

interface I<X extends ValueType>{
  f: (value: X) => void
}

const run = <X extends ValueType>(i: I<X>) => {
  i.f(2)
}
```

Error when using `i.f(2)`

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'X'.   
'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'X', but 'X' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ValueType'.
```

I know this error can be solved using `as`.

But I hope to detect the type of the function parameter before using `as`, like is this parameter a number or a string?

Here is pseudo code to explain.

```js
const run = <X extends ValueType>(i: I<X>) => {
  if (typeof X === 'string'){
    const _f = i.f as (value: string) => void
    _f("jack")
  }else if (typeof X === 'number'){
    const _f = i.f as (value: number) => void
    _f(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're hard-coding a number, might as well just declare your function as `const run = (i: I<number>) => {};` You're going to need to provide a more representative usage example.

Comment: Are you saying you want your function body to be of the form: `if (takesANumber(i.f)) {i.f(2)} else {i.f("x")}`?  If so, then could you [edit] the question to be clear about that, perhaps as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w22QVw)?  The answer will probably be "this is impossible", but at least the question could make it obvious

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the reminder, I will add a pseudocode.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry, this is just a minimization case, and it cannot be directly specified as a number type in practice.

Comment: It's impossible; [parameter annotations](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) are [erased](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) with the rest of the type system; at runtime you don't have `(x: number) => {}`, you have `x => {}` and there's no way to test it. You'll have to give up, or refactor to add runtime type info such as [shown here](//tsplay.dev/mA8PkN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your understanding is correct, you can write it as an answer.  Can you write more about why typescript can't do it now and whether it might be possible in the future? I see that the code of the solution is more complicated, based on this I may give up checking the function type. I think it's acceptable to give up the robustness of the code in this case.

Comment: I’ll do so when I get a chance, might be ~12 hours from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a limitation of TypeScript, it's a limitation of JavaScript. What you actually seem to be wanting to check the `keyof` of is `i.f`'s parameter. JavaScript itself is not a typed language so this doesn't actually exist.

In this case specifically there's actually zero benefit to trying to shove in generics in general. You can just have:

```
interface I {
  f: (value: string | number) => void
}

const run = (i: I) => {
  i.f(2)
}
```

TypeScript is not gonna let you do anything that is impossible with normal JavaScript at runtime.

If your goal instead is to simply ensure that what's passed in is an argument and a `i` that has a `.f` which takes in that type, might I suggest a simpler solution:

```
type ValueType = string | number

interface I<X> {
  f: (value: X) => void
}

const run = <X extends ValueType>(i: I<X>, value: X) => {
    i.f(value)
}
```

This is more in line with the purpose of TypeScript. This prevents the developer from passing in the wrong arguments. It will error out on:

```
run({ f: (x: number) => x + 1 }, 'hi');
```

But accept:

```
run({ f: (x: number) => x + 1 }, 8);
```

Comment: Here's [a TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigZ2AJwEsA7AcygB8pikBbAIwnwFgAoNk4JgMzgGNoASQA8ADQB8UAN5soUbgC4oACgBuiFEtEBKKJkmqA9oQAmbAL5s2fQ8TxR8SYnqhioEAB5diJnLA1oGOLKhEoiEgA0UOrIEFq6+tKyclCEAHTcagHaFlasjsTKUvJKyh5KNAxMCZIeUADUUACMUOZRABzaANxsQA) if you wanna play with this more

Comment: Oh I see @jcalz has already explained the same thing. Sorry first time answering a SO but hopefully the proposed alternatives adds value

Answer (score 2):

The [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) are mostly beside the point, since what you're trying to do isn't even possible for the specific [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of function types involving either `string` or `number`.  So let's refactor to show the issue more clearly:

```
type TakesNumber = { (value: number): void; }
const n1: TakesNumber = x => console.log(x.toFixed(2));
const n2: TakesNumber = x => {}

type TakesString = { (value: string): void; }
const s1: TakesString = x => console.log(x.toUpperCase());
const s2: TakesString = x => {}

function foo(f: TakesNumber | TakesString) {
  if (takesNumber(f)) { f(2); } else { f("x"); }
}

foo(n1); // "2.00"
foo(s1); // "X"
foo(n2);
foo(s2);

// how do we implement this function?
declare function takesNumber(f: TakesNumber | TakesString): f is TakesNumber;
```

**QUESTION:** How can we tell the difference between a function that accepts a `number` argument (`TakesNumber`) and a function that accepts a `string` argument (`TakesString`)?  Equivalently, given a value of type `TakesNumber | TakesString`, how can we write a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (`takesNumber`) which can distinguish between them, so that we can know which argument type to pass?

**ANSWER:** We can't; it's impossible.

The TypeScript type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when the code is compiled to JavaScript.  This includes [parameter type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) like in `(x: number) => {}` or `(x: string) => {}`.  The above code will be emitted as JavaScript like:

```
const n1: TakesNumber = x => console.log(x.toFixed(2));
const n2: TakesNumber = x => {}
const s1: TakesString = x => console.log(x.toUpperCase());
const s2: TakesString = x => {}

function foo(f) {
  if (takesNumber(f)) { f(2); } else { f("x"); }
}

foo(n1);
foo(s1);
foo(n2);
foo(s2);
```

And hopefully you can see that there's nothing reasonable you could do at runtime with the functions `n1`, `n2`, `s1`, and `s2` that would tell you whether they expect a `number` or a `string`.  Maybe if you somehow parsed the function body you could possibly tell `n1` from `s1`, but `n2` and `s2` compile to the identical function `x => {}`, so such information simply does not exist.

So you should not try to do this, because it's impossible.

---

When you want to do something impossible it's likely to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you have a perfectly reasonable underlying use case but you thought you needed to do something impossible to satisfy it.

If your use case is that you will have functions at runtime and you need to be able to examine them to determine whether they take a `string` or a `number`, then one approach that will work is for you to add that information to the functions yourself.

For example, you could add a property called `takesNumber` to a `TakesNumber`, and a property called `takesString` to a `TakesString`:

```
type TakesNumber = {
  (value: number): void;
  takesNumber: any
}

type TakesString = {
  (value: string): void;
  takesString: any;
}
```

And then when you want to distinguish, you just [check whether those keys are `in` the function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
function foo(f: TakesNumber | TakesString) {
  if ("takesNumber" in f) {
    f(2);
  } else {
    f("x");
  }
}
```

Of course that means you need to actually add such a property; if you forget the compiler will warn you:

```
foo((x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed())); // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '(x: number) => void' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'TakesNumber | TakesString'.
```

But if you remember to [add the property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions), then it will work as desired:

```
function n(x: number) { console.log(x.toFixed()) };
n.takesNumber = true;
foo(n);  // this works

function s(x: string) { console.log(x.toUpperCase()) };
s.takesString = true;
foo(s); // this works

foo(Object.assign(
  (x: number) => console.log(x.toFixed()),
  { takesNumber: true }
)); // also works
```

This is more complicated than you wanted, but it has the benefit of being possible.  And of course, maybe there's a better way to satisfy your underlying use case, but whatever that method is, it has to work with TypeScript's type erasure and can't rely on TypeScript itself to provide runtime type information.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgHID2MyBhRSALgJ61IAqIA1tBQK5gARhABOSALx4kACgBumfhABcxQSNEBKVXKoBLACYBuJAF8GRVuy68oAZSai9wAOaTp8xSqRRHzl9pIuoYm5hZIAGb8wPBMelTAkVRUMhGqNnzqYkgAPpw80A5Orpp44UR6EbJMBVACwmKpmqW4kTIATJqhSBAYUHRtAEQAHoNdZuFhjJHRsfGJNbb1GqnptcvZeRn2fiWqVXpQ+UtZ4gTTRKIQTPyiiQCyIEwAFgB0oiDABlRgMqUAPEgAAyvACsSAA9BDiFQkIYICAADSRDB6GBIEBIeD6YCTfDhbHAXzEACMaxODXEUmGkgAfFiElAqBgIK8MFQXDJhq8mFQAGJ6YYQAwdZpGAmMpjEdrkzKU9w0iT01rmaaE4lQMnHQq7NzUukMonM1nsznc3kAVRgtFEAGEQP0-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-okwCFa5GgtJ5Z5zuaL4BU6ZhWcQPLrP1UiOEot2OcA4xXi8hxIAA7pt3BQPi0xiXtPiFWx-gnbNJrnc+Vo2vajrNDd4RQPdthDe4z0QK9zZQMFzWJUcf2iADQMOc2ADyQgAFYQLErwOtVtUyHmh14Qa0M+VyfmvoFmiInmrRqacqjYxM0xilemBMr9-2A+T5imEAA)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. For a specific solution to this question, the one proposed by @Culi appears to be more concise, so I'm currently accepting his answer for now.